# Как узнать текущий размер окна в приложении PyQt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt, resizeevent

Как сделать, чтобы при изменении размера окна, происходило изменение размеров виджетов, которые находятся в нём.

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1000, 834)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 510, 541, 121))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 100, 481, 201))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Main, self).__init__(parent)   
 
    while True:
        width = "определение ширины"
        height = "определение высоты"

        x = width - 1000
        y = height - 834

        Form.resize(1000 + x, 834 + y)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(541 + x, 121 + y)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(481 + x, 201 + y)
```

Comment: через `QWidget.frameGeometry(), или без рамки QWidget.geometry()`

Comment: У виджетов есть для возвращения размера есть метод `size()`. А метод `geometry()` вернет положение виджета и размер

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> QWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
>
> Этот обработчик событий может быть переопределён в подклассе для получения событий изменения размера виджета, которые передаются в параметре события. Когда вызывается resizeEvent (), виджет уже имеет новую геометрию. Старый размер доступен через QResizeEvent :: oldSize ().

Как вариант

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(950, 640)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 510, 541, 121))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 100, 481, 201))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent) 
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.w = self.size().width()     # "определение ширины"
        self.h = self.size().height()    # "определение высоты"
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):        
        width =  self.size().width()    
        height = self.size().height()   
        
        koefW = width / self.w 
        koefH = height / self.h 
        
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(200 * koefW, 510 * koefH, 541 * koefW, 121 * koefH)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(230 * koefW, 100 * koefH, 481 * koefW, 201 * koefH)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: self.pushButton.setGeometry(200*self.koefW, 510*self.koefH, 541*self.koefW, 121*self.koefH)
AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'pushButton' почему выдаёт эту ошибку?

Comment: @5478512 вы запускали скопированный мой пример ?

Comment: @5478512 обратите внимание, что я добавил в ваш пример `self.setupUi(self)`

Comment: Всё, нашёл ошибку. Спасибо!

Comment: @5478512  Никогда не пытайтесь использовать цикл `while True` в основном потоке GUI. Если мой пример решил вашу проблему, не забудьте отметить его как правильный и полезный.